# jQuery animating background color - not working

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-animate, background-color

Anyone see what's wrong with my code? I just can't figure it out!!

The file paths are correct, and if i look in the console when i hover the h3 element, it outputs the text in "hover" just as it should.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>CSS box</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/" src="jquery.color.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#box h3').mouseover(function() {
                console.log('hover');
                $('#box h3').stop(true, true).animate({
                    backgroundColor: '#E4A333'
                }, 200);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="box">
    <h3><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</a></h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer adipiscing consectetur lectus, sed mollis ante dictum id. Nunc magna neque, ornare ac interdum at, pharetra vel leo. Morbi placerat, orci ut sollicitudin dictum, nisi eros feugiat tortor, ac ultricies est leo ac est. Suspendisse justo urna, porttitor eget adipiscing dictum, malesuada nec diam.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

It's suppose to change background color. Unfortunately, it's not working :(

Live link here: (removed)
(will remove in a few hours most likely)

Answer (score 1):

Your script tag for the color plugin is misformed:

```
<script type="text/" src="jquery.color.js"></script>
```

Should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.color.js"></script>
```

Currently it's as if the jQuery.color plugin doesn't exist since it's not being included in the page.

Comment: Thanks Nick! I fixed that, but it still doesn't seem to work for me. :( Take a closer look at it here if you want to.

http://nike1.se/box/

Comment: Tried your link under firefox + firebug, here's what I get : (the French message means that he fails to download the file )
Échec du chargement de la source pour: http://nike1.se/box/jquery-1.4.2.min.js

Comment: Maybe you should try with <script type="text/javascript" src="/box/jquery.color.js"></script> ( and the same for jquery ) ?

Comment: @Nike - Try updating your color plug-in for 1.4: http://github.com/jquery/jquery-color

Comment: Hey David. :) Thanks, but sadly that didn't help either. No difference at all. :/ This is killing me!! :o

Comment: Oh, sorry. Now after refreshing the page a few times, it works! It is however a bit buggy. Is there an alternative for the color plugin?

Thanks a bunch for the help David! :D

Comment: @Nike - See my comment, grab the new version and give it a test.

Comment: Actually, it only seems to work when it feels for it. It doesn't work locally, and now when i go back to the page on nike1.se it doesn't work either :S

Comment: Looks like you're loading jquery from the root of your website and it's not there, it's in the box subdirectory
your script tag should have src="/box/jquery..."

Comment: Yeah, but the index file is located within the box directory. So i'm actually using the right path, which is just the filename in this case. If i would have put the index file in the root directory, i would need to have the "/box/" before the filename. :)

index file: http://nike1.se/box/index.html
jquery files: http://nike1.se/box/jquery....js

Answer (score 0):

Hate to break it to you, but I copied your exact source code and changed your script links to link directly to your javascripts (ie. `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://nike1.se/box/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>`), and it works as expected on my machine.

I suspect the problem is with your paths in the statements on your test page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery.color.js"></script>
```

Your script is actually in the `/box` subdirectory. Perhaps the source links should be `src="query-1.4.2.min.js"` or `src="/box/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"`. Or depending on your web server configuration you might need to include the full path like I did or use the [BASE element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.4) to properly set the base directory of your document.

Comment: that's exactly what I say in the comments above.

Comment: Sorry, yes david, you were right. But how is this possible? Shouldn't the index file look for the jquery files in the same directory? Like the example i posted below..? And thanks Nick, that version works a lot better. :)

Comment: No it won't look for the jquery files in the same directory because you started the path with `/` which signifies the root directory.

Comment: Oh, i had no idea! I set the paths to just the filenames now, and it seems to be working fine for me. Thanks for the help guys, appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to have a background color already applied to the element before you try to animate on it. Try applying a background color to the element in your css or via your js just before your function call.